# Gaming 'Puzzle' Questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Recently (and in the past), there have been questions about gaming related puzzles. Things such as the following (I don't think this is an exhaustive list):

- [What's the name of these games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321079)
- [Which games do the 'K' and 'U' come from in this logo ensemble?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264705)
- [Puzzle - Gears of War](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321064)
- [Cheating/Nintendo Puzzle - Related to gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321089)
- [Which games are these?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209406)
- [What games are these screenshots from?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189258)

In these cases, a puzzle has been created by an unknown entity outside of any game, but the solution to the puzzle would be obtained via experience (or sometimes critical thinking) that revolves around video games.

Are these questions off-topic, if so how?

Comment: I think the chief difference between most of these and the "Cheating/Nintendo Puzzle" is that the rest seem to involve game-id based on images, which technically allows them then to fall into our game-id allowed questions.

Comment: @Ash Yes, the "Gears of War" and "Cheating/Nintendo Puzzle" are definitely different from the others. But both of these (seem) to have some reference to 'Game mechanics and terminology' (on topic per https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
It is definitely a gray area and I don't pretend to know either way; but I am trying to separate that from the game-id criteria.

Comment: The more I think about this issue, the more I think that the game-id questions (with multiple pictures from multiple games) are actually not puzzles. They are 5 or 8 or whatever game ID questions combined into 1. This actually makes them fall into the 'too broad' category, not (as much) the 'off-topic' category

Answer (score 10):

The way I see it, these questions are arbitrary, they're not useful, they're born from a third party, and most importantly they're not issues or questions encountered while playing a game or trying to get a game to run.

While the ones with many small images are similar to game identification questions, they're still asking to solve a puzzle about gaming, rather than helping a user with finding a game they might be interested in.

I'd be happy to see them made off-topic.

Comment: Based on the votes and lack of a dissenting opinion, I'll be adding my votes to close these.

Comment: "they're not issues or questions encountered while playing a game or trying to get a game to run" Why should we limit ourselves to these kinds of questions only?