# Would this idea for a challenge series work on either gaming or gaming meta?

Tags: discussion, community-event, community

I'm from the puzzling stack exchange where questions can be either related to puzzles such as "Who invented X type of puzzle?" or (more often) challenges, particularly where the asker knows the answer and is posing it as a challenge.

I had an idea today that I thought would be fantastic if there was some stack exchange where it would be allowed, and I am wondering if we are allowed to ask challenge questions on this SE too.

The idea is "Where am I?" and the format is to show a non-UI, first person screenshot of some game, and have users try to guess not only which game, but where in that game they are. Would that fit on gaming, gaming meta, or some other SE you know of?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "non-ui screenshot" (what would you screenshot if not the ui?), but game identification questions are on topic iff they have a screenshot. So in a sense we already do this, to an extent.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Hey thanks for commenting. I mean not of the overlay, as that would give away too much information about which game it was... so the question is, is it in scope to do this specifically as a fun challenge, where the asker already knows the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer whether this would work for the rest of the network, so I'll focus on Arqade specifically.

### Main Site

Questions on Arqade are meant to solve problems, so in general, I would hesitate putting non-problems (puzzles/challenges) on the main site. We do have a [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) tag, but in pretty much every instance, we are solving an actual problem; the OP does *not* know what the game is. For example:

- An image of gameplay in [a newspaper article](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/311110/28182)
- A TV show character [playing a game for a few seconds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/77465/28182)
- A user who [found a screenshot on an old computer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19347/28182), and forgot which game it was.

Also note that compilation-style puzzles (multiple cropped images compiled into a single identification challenge) [were deemed off-topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12684/28182) for the main site.

Thus, I don't think it would be a good idea to hold puzzle/challenges on the main site.

### Meta

We have used meta for community-level events before. We've organised community game servers, held movie nights, game nights, and tournaments. More recently, we've been hosting a [Screenshot of the Week](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15753/28182) competition which has seen good community support.

We've also been soliciting ideas for these sorts of things, so ideas like yours are welcome:

- [For which games would you like to see regular events and/or tournaments?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14959/28182)
- [What type of community events would you like to see?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14681/28182)

The problem that I see with hosting your challenge on Meta regularly, is that (as currently described), it sounds like the sort of thing that will attract lots of new meta posts. I don't think we want or need 20+ active 'Where am I?" challenges drowning out actual, pertinent community discussions.

If you were to flesh out the rules of your challenge more fully, altering them slightly so that it could be run out of a single meta post every week or month etc, then it would work for us. Otherwise, it may be more suited to another space (perhaps even in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/)?)

Comment: How does this look? https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15767/where-am-i-this-week-1