# Where am I this Week? Challenge #1 [Submissions closed; participate in the latest version!]

Tags: discussion, community-event, where-am-i-challenge

**This "Where am I?" challenge is now over!** Please participate in the newest question tagged [where-am-i-challenge](/questions/tagged/where-am-i-challenge)!

---

This is the first challenge thread in the "Where am I?" series. Welcome and have fun!

A "Where am I?" challenge involves posting a screenshot from a game and having other users guess in the comments what game it is and where in the game you are. If the game supports turning off the HUD, you are welcome to do that to increase the challenge. The content of the screenshot should contain enough identifiable information to ensure there is only one definitive answer.

**UPDATE:** Screenshots showing procedurally generated environments are fine, it just means the solution will merely be the name of the game rather than the exact location in it. In this case, please state in your challenge that you are only looking for the name of the game and try to make sure that there is not another procedurally generated game which could result in the same scene.

I recommend that questions in this series are locked after two weeks to keep the participation in the most recent challenge.

**Theme**

This is not mandatory but may inspire you to think of a certain environment in some game which would make for a fun challenge. This week's theme is **Peeking Through Grass**.

Comment: I really like this idea, makes people look out for clues together.

Comment: "Games which would not have a definitive answer, such as procedurally generated sandboxes like Minecraft, would not work" so that puts no mans sky out of the question?

Comment: @Topcode That was the idea but it is not a big deal. They can just treat the name of the game as the answer in the case of procedurally generated games. I will update the question with this because I can imagine such a challenge working (especially if you disable the HUD) and I don't want people being criticised unnecessarily.

Comment: alright, that does make sense, would be pretty hard to guess where you are in a few quintillion unique planets

Comment: **Can the serial downvoter please explain their reasoning? This is not constructive at all.** You obviously don't have to, but, as with any democratic system, it will make it easier to address criticism.

Comment: Does the theme recommend the kind of picture they should upload, like "peeking through grass?"

Comment: @Wabbit Yes, and I just put the theme there for inspiration. (start a chat if you have more questions)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123555/discussion-between-wabbit-and-joshua-bizley).

Answer (score 8):

[image]

"In the middle of some world."

I am going to let posters of screenshots decide whether to do this for themselves, but personally I am going to keep a list of the guesses which were not correct.

Hint:

> In the Middle of some Earth.

Solved by Wondercricket:

> The Shire Stocktower, LOTR Online

Comment: Looks medieval, maybe Chivalry? I've never played it however.

Comment: I agree, definitely something medieval. Could that be some location in *Kingdom Come: Deliverance*?

Comment: (Modded) Oblivion?

Comment: Gothic 3, perhaps?

Comment: Based on the hint I would think it was one of the middle earth games, but it sure doesn't look like shadow of mordor...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas If I had to guess (and this is a stretch), possibly somewhere in The Shire in LOTR Online?

Comment: @Wondercricket Yes! That's probably close enough but it is possible to work out exactly where based on the image (it includes one of the landmarks you need for the explorer of the shire deed).

Comment: @JoshuaBizley Official answer: The Shire Stocktower, LOTR Online :)

Answer (score 6):

[image: Where am I?]

The game is probably rather obvious if you've been following my recent questions/contributions ... but *where* exactly I am is a little trickier. I found this place on accident, after all.

---

Credit to user [n00dles](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/170898/n00dles), who correctly guessed the game and got the general location correct. Close enough for company work, at least.

**The Game**

> The Outer Worlds

**The Location**

> Roseway, on Terra 2.
>
>  Specifically, looking East from the top of a hill/mountain that is due West of the Covert Lab. Here is a map of the location where I took the screenshot:
>
>  [image: Map of Roseway]

Comment: Also grass goes weirdly transparent when you crouch in it in this game so it's kind of hard to screenshot. That's alien grass for you, i guess.

Comment: Is it No Man's Sky?

Comment: The Outer Worlds?

Comment: Ah I tried to guess without checking their history, good job

Comment: Yeah I'm one of those people who plays one game, and one game only, in an obsessive fashion until they have beaten it in all conceivable ways and gotten all possible achievements. Also I'd've thought that No Man's Sky would be out of bounds for this challenge since it's procedurally generated.

Comment: That being said, yes, this is "The Outer Worlds". But the question remains -- where in the outer worlds is it?

Comment: See the revised question for the updated policy on procedural generation. Hope you find someone else here who plays this enough to find this location. I have a similar situation with my challenge - it requires someone being quite familiar with the associated game.

Comment: Is it near a high, deep volcano, near a factory or not?

Comment: I haven't played for about a year but I'm pretty sure it's in Emerald Vale to the West. I climbed _everywhere_ in that game lol.

Comment: It's not in Emerald Vale. :)

Comment: Is it the place where you have to kill the tiger-things? That was on the same planet I think...?  I started going through my 914 screenshots but gave up lol (they don't say location names anyway). Have you been to Monarch yet?

Comment: Tiger things? I can't think of anything that looks like a tiger -- are you referring to canids? And yes I've been to monarch -- I've beaten the base game (haven't bought the dlc's yet.)

Comment: I'm tryna guess without Googling. Yeah, Canids look most like tigers lol. I got onto the [border wall and Saltuna factory in Stellar Bay](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D8b2AaxFgjNBCprhB3dBm7MtUHVeOq5W/view?usp=sharing), just thought you'd be interested if you like getting about like me. I'd say you're definately on Terra 2, probably Roseway Gardens. Not sure exactly where though. If there were more [defineable features](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BJ1rdTLXlLsoEaWQn3b-RtOih--auhi8/view?usp=sharing), I might know.

Comment: @n00dles ~ Yeah it's Roseway. There's a cliff due West of the covert lab, I added a map to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

"A completely safe looking hallway"

[image: An interesting floor]

#### Hints:

- > The main character is a Goblin

### Solved!

Correctly identified as

> Styx: Master of shadows

with the location being

> The puzzle floor in the Master Key chapter

by @Joachim and @Lukas Rotter

Comment: Styx: Master of Shadows?

Comment: Well, it's Styx: Master of Shadows. But I have no idea where exactly this is

Comment: The puzzle floor in the Master Key chapter.

Comment: I can't believe anyone actually played Styx. I couldn't stand the gameplay, controls, or death screens

Comment: @PausePause Me neither, and I really don't get why it seems to have gotten a lot of positive feedback, but the silhouette of the goblin protagonist is very recognizable.

Answer (score 4):

**Congratulations to [Lukas Rotter](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/271008/lukas-rotter) for guessing:**

> Forza Horizon 4 - Castleview Road

Note: Blurred because I can't have the answer on screen!

"This is the cheaper spot!"

[image: ???]

Comment: Forza Horizon 4 - Castleview Road

Answer (score 3):

> Dames en heren, dit is uw kapitein die spreekt vanaf de cockpit. We zijn klaar met onze transatlantische oversteek en je zou weer eens land door je raam moeten zien. We hebben nog ongeveer 3 uur vliegen naar Boston. Zoals altijd bedankt voor het vliegen met KLM.

> Ladies and gentlemen, this is your captain speaking from the flight deck. We have finished our transatlantic crossing and you should see land through your window once more. We still have about a 3 hour flight to Boston. As always, thank you for flying KLM.

[image: view out the window of a 777 in the first class cabin]

(note: admittedly this is not as good as I thought but in my defense I thought I had one on the other side of the Atlantic in the passenger cabin; I can't exactly use one in the cockpit with navigation display)

Comment: Also sorry if Google Translate is bad here or if KLM doesn't give passenger announcements in Dutch and English (oh god this livery says Air France too, do they announce in Dutch, English, and French?)

Comment: "Vanaf de cockpit"? Shouldn't that be "vanuit de cockpit"? Has Microsoft skimped on their translations?

Comment: (Oh, or Laminar Research or Aerosoft :)

Comment: That's Google's fault, I just made something up and threw it in translate because I flew Amsterdam to Boston yesterday lol

Comment: I am struggling to find a lake that is shaped just like the one at the bottom left but St Pierre and Miquelon would seem to be the first place you would see land after crossing the Atlantic in that direction? And is it Flight Simulator 2020?

Comment: @JoshuaBizley This is X-Plane 11 so the terrain may be inaccurate. And I guess I should have kept better track of where *exactly* this was, but I'm going to call that close enough, that segment would have been JOOPY DCT TUSKY so about here: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/742399928818466860/835932446532567069/unknown.png - I'll try to do my next one in pure visual conditions in like a city or something in 2020 idk

Comment: Update: There is apparently a freeware helicopter for MSFS so I am now officially Unstoppable with regards to flying around random cities